# Detecting RAZR maxx vs RAZR

Tags: android, motorola

The value for **Build.Model** on the RAZR maxx is exactly the same as on the plain RAZR. It just says "DROID RAZR".

I need to detect which one it is but none of the system values seem to return anything different. Where would one look to find a difference ?

Of course I already tried everything in Build.* (motherboard etc). They are all the same).

Comment: Maybe because it is the same phone, one just has a bigger battery than the other.